# sed creates empty file after replacement operation

Tags: sed

```
sed -i '' 's/|/     /g' largefile.tsv > outfile.tsv
```

I've got a rather large 37 gb file that I'm trying to replace '|' with '\t' but after running for a long time, sed only outputs an empty file (0 bytes).

I'm running on macOS. What am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest creating a smaller subset file that only has a few rows and use that to test your script.

Comment: Apart from not using `-i`, consider using `tr` instead: `tr '|' '\t' < largefile.tsv > outfile.tsv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-i`, the input file changes "in place", and there's no output to redirect to a file.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used sed before so this is very helpful. if I run without the -i will sed output to the desired file?

Comment: Without `-i`, sed outputs to the standard input, which you can redirect with `>` to a file. Note that in such a case, the output file can't be identical to the input one.